# Why can't you destructure to a tuple with only one value?

Tags: c#, destructuring, c#-7.0

In C# 7, it's [apparently](https://msdn.microsoft.com/magazine/mt790184) not possible to destructure to a tuple with only one item.

`ValueTuple<T1>` exists, so it's not because of that.

And backwards compatibility means a `Deconstruct` method with one argument must also be legal:

```
public void Deconstruct(out int i)
```

So why couldn't you write:

```
var (num) = foo;
```

Is it simply that there's no sensible use case for this?

Comment: My guess is that it's to alleviate confusion between `var num = foo` and `var (num) = foo`, especially since it's rare for brackets to change the meaning of a program (excluding order of operations). Such a trade off may not be worth it, since as you point out, it's not *that* useful to destructure a single argument.

Comment: I'd bet on ambiguity with braced identifier expressions in some case.

Comment: In general, 1-tuples and 1-deconstructions raise all sorts of syntax ambiguity. Also, they don't seem very useful.



The feature specs have this restriction built into the grammar at this point (see  https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/docs/features/tuples.md#language-grammar-changes and  https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/docs/features/deconstruction.md#grammar-changes )

Comment: We use optional refs in VB, and want to switch to C# and use tuples (since C# isn't going to add optional refs, which is another issue altogether). But we can't because tuples can't deconstruct just the first return value. Many other languages have 3 dots to skip the remaining values.

Answer (score 5):

My guess: consider the following case:

```
int num;
(num) = foo;
```

If `foo` defines a deconstructor with `out int` and an implicit int cast operator, it will be ambiguous which should be invoked in this case

It is possible to have a compile error in this specific case while allowing the general case I guess, but since, as you mentioned, there is no use case and the syntax would be confusing, maybe it makes sense to not allow it at all

Answer (score 1):

I am working with Visual Studio 2017 RC. I have found that the Connect(); reference that you listed is incorrect. The example syntax that you listed does compile and works.

As a test I used the following code:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Bar { get; set; }

    public void Deconstruct(out int bar)
    {
        bar = Bar;
    }
}

var foo = new Foo { Bar = 3 };
var (num) = foo; //num is an int with a value of 3
var obj = foo; //obj is a Foo object with the same reference as foo
```

In the above example the `num` variable is an `int` with a value of 3. The `obj` variable is a `Foo` object with the same reference as `foo`.

The following does not compile:

```
(int num) = foo; 
(var num) = foo;
//Both give error: The name `num` does not exist in the current context.
```

Comment: Interesting! Let's see what happens once it hits RTM.